# RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration PYTHON

Tags: python, dictionary, runtime-error

I'm trying to remove a key-value from a dictionary by a condition, but when i try i recive the error

RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

Here is my code

```
threading.Timer(5.0, compare_time_connecteds).start()   

FMT = '%H:%M:%S'                                                
datesys_compare = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")     

keys = connecteds.keys()

if len(keys) != 0:
    for i in keys:                   
        true_time = datetime.strptime(datesys_compare, FMT) - datetime.strptime(connecteds.get(i), FMT)    
        difference_in_seconds = true_time.total_seconds()                                   #       

        if difference_in_seconds > 20:               
            connecteds.pop(i)
```

And here is the error

```
 for i in keys:      
 RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

I solved this forcing the *keys* to be a list

```
FMT = '%H:%M:%S'                                                
datesys_compare = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")     

keys = list(connecteds.keys())
```

Comment: Size changing your `dictionary` while looping it is problematic. Try adding keys and values to an empty `dict` unless `difference_in_seconds > 20`

Comment: Just force the keys to be a list and not keys object, to do so: `keys = list(connecteds.keys())`. This happens because the keys object you are iterating over is taking values from the respective dictionary in "real time" and not a static list.

Comment: @Elger thanks so much for your help! This list solve my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the variable `keys` by the expression `connecteds.keys()`. I am assuming that you are using Threads and also that `connecteds` is being used in these threads. May be that is changing the size.